# Printing hidden files and directories using awk

Tags: awk, ls

I have the following command:

```
ls -l /tmp | awk '$3=="'$USER'" {print $NF}'
```

which is supposed to print the name of files and directories under `/tmp` which belongs to the $USER.
It works fine for the normal files and directories but the output doesn't include hidden files and directories which belong to the $USER.

What is needed to fix it?

Comment: Use `ls -la`. `a` shows all files, including hidden ones.

Comment: Why do you think this is an awk issue? If you run the command without piping to awk, do you see the files?

Comment: @Barmar Damn, the problem was that I have `ll` as alias for `ls -laFq` and I was testing the awk with ls and checking the /tmp files with `ll` and this mislead me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to do this:

```
ls -al /tmp | awk '$3==u {print $NF}' u="$USER"
```

or

```
ls -al /tmp | awk -v u="$USER" '$3==u {print $NF}'
```

Comment: Good, this is a cleaner solution! Specially the second alternative. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try: `ls -al /tmp | awk '$3=="'$USER'" {print $NF}'`

Comment: Variables should not be read inside the code, but be declared.